How does one differentiate between an intuition and emotional reasoning?
An intuition is defined as such, as per Google:

the ability to understand something immediately, without the need for conscious reasoning.

But if intuitions don’t involve conscious reasoning, how does one then differentiate an “intuition” from a feeling, which may be stemming from a purely emotional reaction rather than any reasoned process?
Note that as per Google, emotional reasoning is defined to be a cognitive flaw:

"Emotional reasoning" refers to a cognitive distortion where someone believes something is true simply because they feel that way, using their emotions as evidence instead of logic or facts


A few more questions and you will break you record of questions asked under 24 hours :)

Well presumably, intuitions are reasoned, just subconsciously or perhaps quickly @Philomath But I’ve edited it

We can distinguish between types of mental processes based on how effective they typically are at finding the truth.
It could be that you have a mental process - a habitual pattern of activation of neurons - which happens to arrive at the truth more often than not. If this mental process does not involve any conscious reasoning steps, then we might call it "intuition." The key is that it works, even though we can't explain the steps it takes. It's a black box, based on associations and heuristics, similar to how artificial neural networks work.
"Reasoning" based on emotion might be better termed leaping to conclusions based on emotions, rather than reasoning. Such thinking is characterized by fallacies. It's similar to intuition, but what we call "intuition" is something that works, and emotional leaping to conclusions does not. Also, intuition does not need to involve any particular emotion.
"I'm angry at person X therefore person X must have done it," for example, is a type of emotional thinking which is poor at finding the truth. Or "person X is from a different tribe from me, therefore they are guilty." Or "I love person X so they couldn't have done that."
Sometimes, though, emotional thinking is helpful. There is a reason we evolved it - although that reason may be less about finding the truth and more about reinforcing bonds or fighting an enemy tribe.

The answer is already contained in your question:
For a reasoned intuition reason provides some arguments.
While "emotional reasoning" is no reasoning at all.

Agreed in general, though it is unclear whether intuition is truly unreasoned. I am quite aware of how much background processing I do, having compared the rate at which I solve similar problems if I dive into them directly versus if I understand them, set them aside, and then solve them later. We may not be comparing what we think we are comparing.

@keshlam I consider reasoning as a form of thinking to be a - conscious - not unconsicous - process.

His quote says intuition is "without the need for conscious reasoning."

@causative Originally the title said "reasoned intuition". I think the whole post operates with ill-defined, questionable concepts.

@JoWehler conscious reasoning != reasoning. Unconscious reasoning is a thing. These terms are well defined. Your lack of familiarity with them does not make my question ill defined. I only edited the question to make things more clear to (in my eyes) ill formed objections

@Syed It would be helpful if you state your definition of "unconscious reasoning"; thanks.

As per the wiki, “ Unconscious cognition is the processing of perception, memory, learning, thought, and language without being aware of it.” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_cognition

Maybe, that's like a dictionary equating "unconscious" with "not being aware of". - But I asked for your definition of "unconscious reasoning", not for "unconscious cognition".

@JoWehler It is as is termed: reasoning done under the hood. Reasoning that isn’t conscious, perhaps as a heuristic that was consciously reasoned upon earlier. See article here for an in depth discussion: https://academic.oup.com/book/11984/chapter-abstract/161227474?redirectedFrom=fulltext

@Syed Can you provide the 13 pages of the recommended article as an electronic copy?

@JoWehler: If I'm not aware of it happening, I do not consider it a conscious process. Your definition may differ. Your experience may differ.
